# Emacs Recognizes “~/” As HOME Instead of “~/AppData/Roaming/” When SSH to Windows

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows

On Windows, `c:/Users/shynur/AppData/Roaming/` is the `HOME` directory recognized by my Emacs-28.2.  
That's OK, though a little inconvenient.

But when I **ssh to Windows** on PowerShell and then start Emacs, 
Emacs fails to `load` my init-files under `c:/Users/shynur/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/`.  
**I found that Emacs thinks `c:/Users/shynur/` is the `HOME` dir when ssh.**

It means that I must copy my init-files to `c:/Users/shynur/.emacs.d/` before ssh to Windows, each time after editing them under `c:/Users/shynur/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/`.

Why doesn't Emacs think `c:/Users/shynur/AppData/Roaming/` is `HOME` dir when ssh?  
Is there any easy method to avoid redundant copying?  (eg, *symbolic link*, but I don't know whether Windows has implemented it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer says, you should read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html) pertaining to setting up emacs on windows.

That being said, the fix (other than RTFM) is to set the environment variable HOME manually in whatever way is most convenient (I find the advanced system properties method described [here](https://superuser.com/a/549450/259056) easiest). As you've discovered powershell does this for you within a powershell session, so you can take the value that it uses and set HOME to that so emacs uses the same directory. Don't forget to move your init files and change anything that assumes your emacs lives in appdata.

If you really wanted to keep your .emacs.d inside that appdata folder for whatever reason you could reset the variable HOME in your powershell profile.ps1, by unsetting it with -Force then resetting to the appdata folder, as shown in the solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82053/setting-home-in-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

Please read [chapter H.5 HOME and Startup Directories on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html) of the Emacs manual. It is probable that `sshd` is creating your shell with an explicit `HOME` variable that doesn’t match Emacs’ default.